# AWS Sagemaker very common transient errors on spot training jobs, only in us-west-2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using Sagemaker in us-west-2 to train multiple ML models. Here is my configuration for most of these jobs:

- Mostly G5 instances, some G4 instances
- Spot Training Jobs
- Have one bucket in S3 fed as FastFile with multiple entrypoints
- Custom Image from ECR

I previously ran very similar jobs in us-west-1, and there was never a problem. However, after having migrated to us-west-2, this is happening often for multiple jobs:

- Some jobs will fail in a few seconds, as soon as they enter the "Starting" state.
- Some jobs will fail after 30+ minutes.

All failed jobs have the same message, with no extra information and no suspicious logs in CloudWatch whatsoever. The message is: "InternalServerError: We encountered an internal error. Please try again."

Nothing in my code has changed to cause such errors. My ECR image is ~14GB (much less than the 25GB limit).

If I resubmit jobs that fail in a few seconds, then within a few tries I can get them to run. This is with no change to anything, other than just resubmitting my job with a script I have (that also makes no changes other than the name of the job).

There is high CPU utilization (>100%) for the jobs that run for 30+ minutes before failing - but there are also jobs running almost the same code that go to completion (hours+) with much higher utilization.

Considering that some jobs do run, I am assuming that this can only be a transient error with some instances. However, this happens far too often (50+% of all jobs that I run) for it to be acceptable.

I assume this has to be some issue with us-west-2 because everything worked fine in us-west-1 (albeit only on g4dn instances), but the error message and logs provide absolutely no extra help. Please help!

Comment: This is a service side issue we should ask them to raise a ticket with SageMaker Support